# How do I split the output in C# when iterating through an array after sorting it?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, for-loop, insertion-sort

I have the following situation:

First of all I enter the amount of data I want to insert into my array.
After that I insert 2 values (with a space between them by using `Split()`) on each line into an array which together form a fraction.
So here comes that code:

```
int amount = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
double[] data = new double[amount];
for (int x = 0; x < amount; x++)
{
    string[] spaces = Console.ReadLine().Split();
    data[x] = Double.Parse(spaces[0]) / Double.Parse(spaces[1]);       
}
```

So for example I insert the following values:

```
2
1 2
2 2
```

Then it will create the fraction 1/2 and 2/2 which equals 0.5 and 1.

After I have inserted those values, the `for` loop will sort it so it all stands in a non-decreasing order. So here is that part of the code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    value = data[i];
    j = i - 1;
    while (j >= 0 && data[j] > value)
    {
        data[j + 1] = data[j];
        j--;
    }
    data[j + 1] = value;
}
```

And finally there is a for-loop that iterates through the array to display the new sorted array-data:

```
for (int y = 0; y < amount; y++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(data[y]);
}
```

So my problem is that I still do not know (after a lot of trying and searching) how to get the output to be like this:

So if I enter the following:

```
3 --> Amount
2 2
1 2
1 3
```

I will get the following output:

```
1 3
1 2
2 2
```

Instead of the fractions so `0.333`, `0.5` and `1`.

I know I have to delete the `/` operator but I do not know what else to do.

Comment: why are you doing your own sort implementation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Well i wanted to give this way a go, since it's one of the methods for me to learn the basics in datastructures, but the sorting works perfectly, only the output is not the way it's supposed to be.

Comment: I'm confused.  What is the output you want?  (Also, last time I checked, 1/3 < 1/2 so your sort is broken.)

Comment: Sry that was my bad, i edited it in the question, the loop is working. The output i want is just those numbers again that i put in the console but sorted, so in the way you see it in the output section of the question.

Answer (score 3):

When you take in your information, you are converting the fractions into a decimal.  What you need to do is keep the fractions around so that you can write them back out afterwards.  I would start with a structure:

```
class Data
{
  double Value { get { return Numerator / Denominator } }
  double Numerator { get; set; }
  double Denominator { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can sort these by `.Value`, and when you write it out, you can write it out by `Numerator + " " + Denominator`

In your sort, use the value:

```
value = data[i].Value;
--
while(j >= o && data[j].Value > value)
```

Moving the objects stays the same.

When printing use the Numerator & Denominator

```
Console.WriteLine(data[y].Numerator + " " + data[y].Denominator);
```

Comment: This makes sense. The only other option of which I can think it to write a bunch of code to convert a decimal to a fraction. That would be a lot of work.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin In addition to being a fair bit of work, given the issues with the limited precision of floating point types, wouldn't result in you getting your original fractions (at least in many cases).

Comment: Good point. How would it know to output 2 2 instead of 1 1 or 7 7, for instance?

Comment: Kyle, I wouldn't store the `Value` in such a type, but rather have it be a read only computed value based on the other two; then you don't need to worry about keeping the values in sync.

Comment: I don't understand how i have to implement this. So do i have to make a multiple objects and assign them those values? Or do i have to make an array and put the objects in there?

Comment: @Servy Yeah I thought about that, but kept it in there since that's the way the OP was doing it.  I'll update it.

Comment: @A.Mohseni Updated for you

Comment: You might change the Numerator and Denominator to int to better model a fraction. (But still return a double for the Value).

Answer (score 0):

Kyle W's answer is what you want. I'll just add one detail:

You can add the following method to your `Data` class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("{0} {1}", Numerator, Denominator);
}
```

Then, when you print out the elements of the data array, you can simply do this:

```
foreach(var item in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```

That will automatically call the ToString() method on data, and give you the output you want.  At a later point, you could change the method to be something like the following without having to change your output loop:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("{0} {1}. Decimal Value: {2}", Numerator, Denominator, Value);
}
```

Now, your output also displays the Value, showing that this is a very intuitive and flexible way of doing output for your class.